# Java - Generic Type como parametro do metodo readEntity do jax rs client

Tags: java, jersey, jax-ws

Quero abstrair um metodo post do meu codigo, utilizando generic type pra facilitar a implementação. O código é um cliente de ws usando jax-rs. Segue

```
public T2 post(T1 requisicao, String path){
    javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(Cliente.HOST).path(path);
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request();
    Response response = invocationBuilder
            .header("chave",Cliente.CHAVE)
            .header("Content-type",Cliente.CONTENT_TYPE)
            .header("Accept",Cliente.ACCEPT)
            .post(Entity.json(requisicao));
    T2 resposta = null;
    resposta = response.readEntity((Class<T2>) resposta.getClass());
    return resposta;
}
```

E aqui como utilizar o metodo:

```
public RespostaCadastroUsuarioSistema cadastraUsuarioSistema(RequisicaoCadastrarUsuarioSistema modeloRequisicao){
    Cliente<RequisicaoCadastrarUsuarioSistema,RespostaCadastroUsuarioSistema> cliente = new Cliente<>();
    return cliente.post(modeloRequisicao, "caminho/para/o/metodo");
}
```

Por motivos óbvios, o codigo acima da NullPointException. O problema é que eu não consegui pensar em uma forma de fazer isso funcionar, já que não posso instanciar uma classe do tipo T2 por ser genérico e o método readEntity do javax.​ws.​rs.​core.​Response não aceita generic type como parâmetro.

Sabem se é possível? Ou vou ter que trabalhar com interface e fazer cast do retorno do método?

Comment: Por que você não passa a classe que o método deve retornar como um argumento para o método?

Comment: Funcionou, más eu entendo que o generic type é justamente pra não precisar fazer isso. Tenho a classe passada duas vezes, na definição da classe cliente (T2) e no parâmetro. Não há outra forma?

Comment: Você está usando Java 8? Se sim, creio que uma saída funcional seria muito mais adequada. Algo como `public <A,R> R post(A requisicao, String path, Function<Response, R> geradorRetorno)`, e no bloco final eu teria apenas `return geradorRetorno.apply(response);`. Creio que a chamada a essa função se tornaria então `cliente.post(modeloRequisicao, "caminho/método", r -> r.readEntity(RespostaCadastroUsuarioSistema.class));`

Comment: Ai ficou bonito. Obrigado. Elabora uma resposta por favor.